# Converting array of Objects to array of custom Types

Tags: java, arrays, list, reflection, toarray

I have a method to build the array for the required type. It works for the primitive types. But when I have array of custom objects it doesn't work. So I have tweaked it. But still it fails. 
 Code is like this :

```
    private Object buildArray(  String type,   Object object) {
    final Class<?> requiredType =  loadClass(type);
    final String typeName = type.substring(2).replace(";", "").trim();
        Object[] array = ((Object[]) object);
        ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>(array.length);
        for (Object customObj : array) {
            arrayList.add(castToRequiredType(typeName, customObj));
        }
        return arrayList.toArray();
 }
```

In this `castToRequiredType` : casts the `CustomObject` to the `CustomType` where `CustomType` is a class. And array to be build is of type `CustomType`. I am stuck at dynamically building the array of `CustomType`.

Any help in this direction is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The intention of this code is really hard to understand. What is your overall goal with this?

Comment: overall goal is to invoke the API which takes a parameter of type customObject[]. And each CustomObject I have to build using castToRequiredType. This CustomObject can be MyCustoType, YourCustomType etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks I have solved it using [Axis's Array Util For the same](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/apiDocs/org/apache/axis/utils/ArrayUtil.html#convertArrayToObject%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class%29)

Answer (score 2):

If you have an array of `Object`, you can use [`Arrays.copyOf`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28U%5B%5D,%20int,%20java.lang.Class%29) to convert it to a different type:

```
CustomType[] ca = Arrays
  .copyOf(array, array.length, CustomType[].class);
```

---

Comment: Well i tried replacing the last like like this                                                            return Arrays.copyOf(arrayList.toArray(), arrayList.size(),
                    customType.newInstance()); but it doesn't compile The method copyOf(U[], int, Class<? extends T[]>) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (Object[], int, capture#40-of ?) Thanks for help :)

Comment: @java_enthu: There was a mistake in my answer, but I fixed it. This line replace your `for`-loop. You do not need to construct an `ArrayList` first. This works directly with your `array`.

Comment: @space_cowboy : I replace loop by    Class<?> customType =  loadClass(typeName);
            Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length,customType);Still i am getting the same compilation error. he method copyOf(U[], int, Class<? extends T[]>) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (Object[], int, Class<capture#40-of ?>)

Comment: @java_enthu: Sorry, It seems that indeed this approach does not work if class is not known at compile time.

Comment: Anyway thanks for quick help :) Any other approach or work around do  you see which will be feasible?

Comment: I edited the answer to fix the compilation error, it must be CustomType[].class and not CustomType.class !